# How to troubleshoot Windows 10 random long delays?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, freeze, hardware-failure

My desktop computer experiences random long delays where all windows freeze for 20-30 seconds or so, then goes back to normal. Happens once or twice a day. Sometimes the mouse freezes, too. Sometimes it doesn't. I know the F: drive has to spin up after it's idle, but that's pretty predictable. This is different. I have SysInternals' process explorer running in the system tray, and it's not showing any CPU-bound process or anything. The logs don't tell me anything either.

**How do I even *start* to troubleshoot an issue like this?**

My computer is several years old, and was a Windows 10 upgrade from Win7. It's been through at least a few hardware changes along the way. For instance, I had a mirrored disk and one of the mirrors conked out (and I've taken it off line).

**To be clear, I'm seeking an effective view into what's going on at those key moments. Or a fix. Or a clear explanation as to why it can't be fixed, with references.**

Comment: Look in Reliability History (Control Panel, Security and Maintenance) and see if Windows Explorer "Stopped Working" at the same time as the computer appears to freeze.

Comment: Have you checked your disks for SMART errors?

Comment: An outside possibility: Is the PC connected by WiFi or Ethernet, and do you have wireless mouse or keybaord? Recently, I noticed problems with new, high-speed, routers interfering with wireless accessories. When throughput was high, the RF-enabled hardware froze or worked *very* slowly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, everyone -- I wasn't aware of _Reliability History_ or _SMART error_ checking, but both tell me things are OK.  I wondered, too, if some type of network transient is involved. I don't have a wireless mouse, but use bluetooth headphones.  I'll try to watch these going forward and report back.

Comment: Nothing helpful in the event logs? Did you manage to eliminate any hardware as the cause?

Comment: Please detail your RAM amount, PC model if possible, & what applications you have open while the issue is happening as thats likely to help

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers. I'm trying to figure out if my symptoms are better after fiddling around with a couple things on the USB side, since it only happens once in a while. I owe it to you guys to pay the bounty and I will.

Answer (score 2):

Use Windows Performance Analyzer. It offers you the most information about what is happening with Windows system regarding performance.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/windows-performance-analyzer

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/cpu-analysis

Answer (score 0):

Good question that you worded fairly well, however its a hard question. I've been in a helpdesk tech for 10yr & am still trying to figure out stuff like this with no super clear answer. I asked you in a comment to detail your RAM amount, PC model, & what apps you have opening during these freezes as that will help guide advice. Here are my suggestions w/o that info:

1. Run HW diagnostics so you can eliminate HW as a culprit. Dell & HP I know have a hard drive test built-in you trigger at power-on (F12 & F9/F10 I think). Run all diagnostics not just HDD. If you don' have built-in diagnostics download some. I prefer UltimateBootCD (UBCD)

   1a. I'd concentrate on RAM tests then HDD tests. UBCD I mentioned above bundles alot of various tools, for RAM it has memtest86 which runs continually until you stop it. I'd personally let it run for two iterations, I think it shows that in one of the top corners. HDD tests & S.M.A.R.T. info can be run from smartmontools which is a linux utility you can trigger in Parted Magic a live linux distro on that UBCD
2. I had an issue like that with my custom built-PC day 1 after installing Windows. I am quite sure mine was caused by a RAM timing issue I fixed in BIOS. I can't tell you how I fixed exactly, I just know having the RAM 'timing' info (in its tech specs) & tweaking BIOS options to match I think fixed my issue
3. If you run many apps or internet tabs & 4GB RAM or less I think you need more RAM. I've had this issue on work PC's lately & indeed I saw low CPU during the freeze/slow times. I think RAM was fully utilized so Windows went to the page file which is on the hard drive so is slower causing the delay. Worsening the problem is if you moved page file to another drive that isn't used then when Windows needs it the HDD has to spin-up as it slept from idleness possibly
4. Update BIOS, Firmware (FW), & lastly drivers. I know everyone tells you to do it, but I'd focus on the BIOS & FW first as those regulate CPU, RAM, etc.
5. Try to repair Windows, 3 ways:

   5a. admin command prompt, `sfc /scannow`

   5b. admin command prompt, [`DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/deployment/fix-windows-update-errors)

   5c. boot Windows CD/USB, see if there is repair option
6. Scour ALL Event Viewer which is confusing & takes a long time, but may bring some insight
7. Look at doing a Windows Reset (from Settings) or total wipe & reload. Either way it resets a bunch of stuff & is annoying. This is becoming 'process of elimination'
8. If possible look at adding more RAM and/or an SSD which helps any old PC, but also seemingly relates to the issue-at-hand

Answer (score 0):

I have an NVIDIA graphical card.
I've been having random freezes also on my computer for many months.
I noticed that the freezes involved also the freezing of the screen, so decided
that the problem was the NVIDIA graphical driver.

As the freezes continued for months across NVIDIA driver updates,
I decided to go backwards.

I finally arrived to driver version
[451.67](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/results/162105/),
where the freezes have disappeared. My theory is that the driver tries
unsuccessfully to "phone home" to NVIDIA, freezing the computer in the
meantime. I haven't dared upgrade the driver since then.

If you also have an NVIDIA card, you might also try downgrading to
version 451.67, which can simply be installed over the existing driver.
Do not forget to disable automatic updates in the NVIDIA Control Panel.